# New washing machine. Why we have to perform a cleaning cycle?

Tags: washing-machine

I have few questions regarding as to **why** we have to do few things on new washing machines.

I ran the first wash on quick wash to check if nothing is leaking, but after checking the manual, I see that it is suggested:

1. Manually pour 2 liters of water into detergent compartment and add detergent.
2. And run the program with 90°C.
3. Run it empty.

Why do we have to pour water manually into the machine?
Why we have to run it with 90°C(basically a cleaning program)  on the first use?

As a side note, should I do this after the fact that I already did 40°C quick wash with a towel in it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does the machine reach 90C?  Does it have an internal water heater?  I can't imagine you have a water heater at that temp?

Comment: @JPhi1618 Washing machines have heating element inside of them. They suck in cold water and heat it to the desired temperature. I guess it's up to manufacturers whether to include certain temperatures. The ones I was picking from (Siemens/Bosch) both have temperature max at 90°C.

Comment: Ah, ok.  It seems like I had heard that before but had forgotten.  In the US, clothes washers do not have heaters.  They take hot and cold water from the tap and mix them to the desired temperature and the hot typically maxes out around 50C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the same reason that any dishes or glassware that you buy says to wash it before you use it.  They really try to keep everything clean at the factory and chances are your glasses (or washer tub) are spotless, but they can't guarantee it.

To be absolutely sure your new white sheets don't end up with blobs of gear grease all over them because of a glob that wasn't noticed, they want you to to a hot wash with no clothes.  This cleans the tub and if there's a mechanical problem or leak, you find out with just water rather than 40lbs of wet clothes.

I would do the hot cycle as recommended just to be totally sure.  If you're just doing a load of old towels, maybe you can skip it since you did do a warm wash already.  Heat will help loosen oils and grease which is probably why they specify the 90C wash.

Comment: In most appliance manufacturing plants, they don't bother cleaning the metal parts before shipping, because the cost and time to ensure they are dry before packing them is prohibitive and if they left just a little water on something, it grows mildew in transit. So the machinery oil used in stamping presses and casting mold release agents for cast parts is all still there when you receive it.